# jquery checkbox issue - do not check if it's disabled

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 5 checkboxes in each row. The first one is 'ALL'. I am trying to see if any of the others are disabled. So, if somebody clicks on 'ALL' checkbox, I need to make sure the disabled ones are not checked. This is what I have:

```
("input[name^=all_]").each(function() {
var input = $(this);   
var name = input.attr('name');    
var num = /\d+$/.exec(name)[0]; 
$(this).click(function() {

if ($('"#G"+num').attr('disabled',false)) {            
$("#G"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
}
if ($('"#E"+num').attr('disabled',false)) {         
$("#E"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
}
if ($('"#W"+num').attr('disabled',false)) {
$("#W"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
}
if ($('"#S"+num').attr('disabled',false)) {
$("#S"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
}
});
```

});

The thing is, the disabled ones still gets checked once I click on 'ALL'. what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: interesting things happened

      if (!$("#G"+num).attr('disabled','disabled')) {      
 $("#G"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
 }
 if (!$("#E"+num).attr('disabled','disabled')) {   
 $("#E"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
 }
 if (!$("#W"+num).attr('disabled','disabled')) {
 $("#W"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
 }
 if ($('"#S"+num').attr('disabled',false)) {
 $("#S"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
 }
 });
it does not check the disabled box,but the enabled box becomes disabled

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this works:

```
 if ( !$("#G"+num).is(':disabled') ) {             
$("#G"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
}
if ( !$("#E"+num).is(':disabled')) {            
$("#E"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
}
if ( !$("#W"+num).is(':disabled') ) {
$("#W"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
}
if (!$("#S"+num).is(':disabled')) {
$("#S"+num).attr('checked', $("#all_"+num).is(':checked'));
}
});
```

Answer (score 10):

To **check** all except disabled

```
$('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').attr('checked','checked');
```

To **uncheck** all except disabled

```
$('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery's ":disabled" filter instead of accessing the 'disabled' attribute.

Comment: like this ? if (!$("#S"+num).filter(':disabled'))
this doesn't work, the active buttons don't get checked.

Answer (score 3):

umm i would probably do this:

```
    $('input[name=all]').click(function(){
        var classn = $(this).attr('class');
        $('.'+classn+':not(:disabled)').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
```

just assign a uniform class for every row say row_one, row_two and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var all_checks = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#all").click(function(){ 
    $('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').attr("checked",!(all_checks==1));
         if (all_checks == 0){all_checks=1;} else {all_checks = 0;};
    });
});
```

Where #all is the ID of the master checkbox (which says Check/Uncheck All...

Hope this helps somebody! Richard Reveron

Answer (score 1):

It might be better UI to use a toggle button to "check all/uncheck all" instead of a checkbox for "ALL".  So 1 button + 4 checkboxes instead of 5 checkboxes. Then you won't have to mess with disabling.

Comment: The page is being created from a db output. Each record has different available options, so i had to disable the checkboxes to indicate that option is not available for that particular record. Not sure, if toggle option would work in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, but I managed to solve it & I think the solution is fine. Here:

```
$("INPUT[@name="+children+"][type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $(parent).is(':checked'));
$("INPUT[@name="+children+"][type='checkbox'][disabled]").attr('checked', false);
```

I think it's easy to understand. No need to explain further, I guess :P
But please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had another similar take on it where I wanted to check all check boxes that were not disabled.  However, I also have a few other checkboxes that I don't want affected by this, so I needed to target just the `<div>` that contained them:

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkAll').click(function () {
        $('#completed_modules').find(':checkbox:not(:disabled)').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Works like a charm.  Enjoy, I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it on this way.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all">
<span style="font-weight: bold">Check All</span>
</label>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#check-all").click(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        $('input:checkbox:not(:enabled)').removeAttr('checked');
    });
</script>
```