# Select all checkbox elements except disabled ones

Tags: jquery

I want to select all `checkbox` elements expect disabled ones,

this is my html

```
<input id="chkSelectAll" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />Select All

<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_listItem_pnlDis_0">
    <input id="checkApproved" type="checkbox" name="checkApproved" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">
</div>
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_listItem_pnlDis_8" class="dis">
    <input id="checkApproved" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$listItem$ctrl8$checkApproved">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#chkSelectAll').click(function () {
    var checked_status = this.checked;
    //   alert(checked_status);
    $('div#item input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        this.checked = checked_status;
    });
})
```

it's working for selecting all `checkbox` elements but I want to skip disabled ones.

How can I do that?

Comment: `$('div#item input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')`

Comment: probable duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723649/jquery-checkbox-issue-do-not-check-if-its-disabled

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery select all if not disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457050/jquery-select-all-if-not-disabled)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use not() to exclude things with a disabled attribute.

```
$('#chkSelectAll').click(function () {
    var checked_status = this.checked;

    $('div#item input[type=checkbox]').not("[disabled]").each(function () {
               this.checked = checked_status;
    });
});
```

more concise

```
$('#chkSelectAll').click(function () {
    var checked_status = this.checked;
    $('div#item input[type=checkbox]').not(":disabled").prop("checked", checked_status);
});
```

Comment: @SizS: You don't need a `.each`. You can also just do `$('input[type=checkbox]').not(":disabled").prop('checked', checked_status);` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/umT6a/)

Comment: And probably the more common way of using the selector would be not(":disabled").

Answer (score 3):

It can be as short as

```
$('#chkSelectAll').click(function() {
    $('div#item :checkbox:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hRc4a/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#chkSelectAll').click(function () {
    var checked_status = this.checked;

    $('div#item input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
           if (!this.disabled) 
               this.checked = checked_status;
    });
});
```

or without the each loop :

```
$('#chkSelectAll').on('click', function() {
    var checked_status = this.checked;

    $('div#item input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function(i, prop) {
         return this.disabled ? prop : checked_status;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#chkSelectAll').click(function () {
        var checked_status = this.checked;
        //   alert(checked_status);
        $('div#item input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
             if(!$(this).is(':disabled'){
                 this.checked = checked_status;
             }

        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may also use the :not selector as follows:

```
$('#chkSelectAll').click(function () {
    var checked_status = this.checked;
    $('div#item input[type=checkbox]:not(:disabled)').each(function () {
               this.checked = checked_status;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$('#chkSelectAll').change(function(){
    var self = this;
    $('input:checkbox').filter(function(){
        return !this.disabled
    }).prop('checked',self.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/H4Qhf/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: I would assume that running the `filter` method is a lot slower than simply using the `not` selector.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: a point I hadn't considered, strangely: dammit, now I have to go JS Perf-in' to test. (Well, after dinner, anyway...)

Comment: I was wondering the same thing:  http://jsperf.com/not-vs-filter I added checking and unchecking for each permutation. Not sure if it is written well enough but have a play around and see if you can improve on it. I would assume the reason `filter` is slower is because it makes a collection of everything first and then iterates through them all to exclude the disabled ones. While the `not` selector would not select/return the disabled ones to begin with. I suppose it also makes sense to only return what you need to begin with if possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Check all except disable

```
$('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

### Uncheck all except disable

```
$('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').removeAttr('checked');
```

refer below link for more details http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-check-all-except-disabled/18#.V00SYfl97IU

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest this solution if you want select all rows except disabled one.

**Just add this code in checkbox input(HTML)**

```
onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']:not(:disabled)').prop('checked',this.checked);"
```